# Ceiling(convert(decimal,decimalvalue)) vs Ceiling(convert(float,decimalvalue))

Tags: sql

When we do Ceiling(convert(decimal,8.09)) then result is 8 and in Ceiling(convert(float,8.09)) result is 9, explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DECIMAL` Type in SQL Uses a Precision numeric data type instead of an Approximate numeric data type like a `FLOAT`. What this implies is that the data stores not only the number but a dimension of how precise it can be, whilst in comparison a float is always a scaled approximation store for a numeric value.

There are 3 pieces to the `DECIMAL` precision, the value, the P number (for precision) and S number (for scale). The P number is the maximum number of digits that the data type can store so if I have a `DECIMAL` with a precision of 4 I can only go upto 9999 or as low as 0.001. The default is 18 digits.

The problem you are having is your S number. The S number is the precision of the numbers after the decimal point, a sort of sub-set maximum on top of the P number. So a S precision of 2 means I can have .01 to .99, precision of 4 is .0001 to .9999 and so on. This in combination with P can lead to truncation if you don't account for the maximum digits. So although a conversion of the number 12345.12345 (P,S) = (6,3) should have the 3 decimal digits (`12345.123`), the maximum digits are 6 so you end up with (`12345.1`) In order to have an S number the P number must also be declared:

```
DECIMAL(P[,S])
```

In this way, due to the construction limits of P and S, P cannot be smaller than S and S not smaller than 0 (you cannot have 14 decimal places in a number which the maximum digits is only 5) :

```
P >= [S] >= 0
```

To solve your problem, when you do your `CONVERT`, declare how precise you need your decimal to be as, by default, the `S` value is set to **0** :

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,6), 8.09)
```

Here are a few examples to show the precision, run them and see how they work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1) , 12.345678)  --10 Maximum Digits, 1 Decimal Places (Expect round off)

SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,3)  , 12.2345)     --18 Maximum Digits, 3 Decimal Places (Expect 3rd decimal round up)

SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,4)  , 123.456789) --3 Maximum Digits, 4 Decimal Places (Expect 4th decimal round up, but get overflow error as P < S )

SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,6) , 8.09)       --18 Maximum Digits, 6 Decimal Places (Expect no data change in precision)
```

I hope that helps you out, if possible always use decimal and specify a precision where you know there are bounds. It can be more efficient depending on the data and nature of the procedure.

Comment: Thank you @Mitch Wheat, appreciate the comment and +1!

Answer (score 1):

This is a precision issue.

Because

```
convert(decimal,8.09) == 8
```

whereas

```
convert(float,8.09) == 8.09
```

`decimal` has a default precision of 18

`float` is `float(53)` (also a synonym for double) which has 15 digit precision

What are you actually trying to do? What is the context?

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually i am doing performance tuning of some large Store procedure and i found some query statement which use this conversion so i replaced "float" with decimal and wanted to check performance, but i forget to define precision so got wrong result so asked question. nway thanks again.